# Detect visual rows of HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, scrolltop

An example use case: I have a long list of elements that need to be animated when visible.
I need a detection via JavaScript when a new "visual" row starts.

Is there a way to check the position of elements and tell with some px tolerance which element in a list is on a new visual row?

Maybe using something like scrollTop position?

Comment: what did you try and where can we see that result?

Answer (score 0):

so what about this,
you use a function that selects each item in your long list of elements classed `myelements` class
check their visibilty property value
do something based on that value

so something like this

```
function checkVisibilty(){
    $('.myelemets').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            //animate me
        }
    });
}
```

Afterward, you can call the function periodically
`window.setInterval(checkVisibilty, 100);`